# C# Dictionary changes when source changes

Tags: c#, dictionary, datagridview

When iam adding a DatagridviewRow to a Dictionary and Delete the DatagridviewRow also the Datagridviewrow in Dictionary changes. But i dont want the Dictionary to change

```
        Dictionary<int, CustomDataGridViewRow> _cache = new Dictionary<int, CustomDataGridViewRow>();

        public void add(int index, CustomDataGridViewRow row)
        {
            _cache.Add(index, row);
        }


        this.Rows.RemoveAt(1);
```

I tried a to clone the row, but i dont make a copy of the row, it makes a new row. look at this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you need to clone the object before you add the dictionary entry.

A dictionary doesn't contain objects - it contains *references*. The dictionary itself *isn't* changing - it just contains a reference to the object which has changed.

If your object supports cloning, you can just use:

```
public void Add(int index, CustomDataGridViewRow row)
{
    _cache.Add(index, (CustomDataGridViewRow) row.Clone());
}
```

You may want to see the docs for [`DataGridViewRow.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.clone.aspx) for more details though...

Either way, it's *very* important that you understand how reference types work in C#, otherwise you'll keep bumping into this time and again.

Comment: Look at picture above. Clone does not makes a "clone" it makes a new row with index -1. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: So set the `Index` property explicitly if you must... although I don't think it makes much sense, given that the new row won't be associated with a `DataGridView`. You haven't said what you're trying to *achieve* with any of this...

Comment: I'm an idiot ahw . I've missed something
works for now, thank you. Sorry for last comment

Answer (score 2):

When you are adding `row` to the dictionary, you are adding a *reference* to the row.

This means that changes to the row are seen by all references to it.

You can avoid this by providing a *copy* of the row to the dictionary (aka a clone).

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary only contains a reference, clone the item first:

```
_cache.Add(index, row.Clone());
```